# How to import lodash directly into a custom namespace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, namespaces, underscore.js, lodash

I would like to import **lodash core v4.14.1** from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.14.1/dist/lodash.core.js. However, simply executing the link adds the library to the global namespace, i.e., **window**. How can I add the library *directly* into a custom namespace, say, **window.myns**? Please note that I don't want to add the library to the global namespace and make a reference to it after.

Comment: Note that github is not a CDN!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lodash's [`_.noConflict()`](https://lodash.com/docs#noConflict) to free `_` and assign it to a new alias:

```
window.myns = _.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use exactly the linked version of lodash it will always register into `window`, because that's the way it was build (you can seed this if you scrool to the bottom of the implementation, there is the "export" mechanism).

Guess you have to use some sort of module loader if you want to put it into a namespace. It would be interesting *why*  you want to put it in its own namespace. Because `window._` and `window.namespace._` is pretty much the same.

Comment: That's what I thought. I think I will investigate if Node.js can help me. I know that the outcome is pretty much the same but all my code is loaded as a third party to my client's site, and I am only allowed work within 1 namespace.